# How to simplify this `checking database value` script?

Tags: php

I make a php script to check value before update. This script is working fine. But, I wonder how to simplify this. If there are hundred of column to be checked then it's make hundred of php lines.

```
public function edit_project_master(){
    $no_pro     = 'PRJ-2017-501'; //
    $na_pro     = $this->input->post('na_pro'); //value for edit
    $ja_pro     = $this->input->post('i_metode'); //value for edit      

    $check_pro  = $this->MProject->get_det_pro($no_pro); //get data form table

    //checking script
    foreach($check_pro as $res_check_pro){

        if($na_pro != $res_check_pro['NAMA_PROJECT']){  //IF VALUE DIFFERENT
            $col_name;

            foreach($res_check_pro as $key_pro => $val_pro){
                if($res_check_pro['NAMA_PROJECT'] == $val_pro){
                    $col_name = $key_pro;            //GET COLUMN NAME
                }
            }

            $data['ACTIVITY']       = "UPDATE";
            $data['OLD_VALUE']      = $res_check_pro['NAMA_PROJECT'];
            $data['NEW_VALUE']      = $na_pro;
            $data['COL_AFFECTED']   = $col_name;
            $data['TABLE_AFFECTED'] = "PM_REQUIREMENT_PROJECT";  //How to get table name automatically??
            $data['ANNOTATION']     = NULL;
            $data['EXECUTOR']       = $this->session->userdata('nip');
            $data['CHANGED_ON']     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data['CHANGED_BY']     = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $data['STATUS']         = 1;

            $this->MProject->ins_system_log($data);             
        }

        if($ja_pro != $res_check_pro['JADWAL_PROJECT']){
            $col_name;

            foreach($res_check_pro as $key_pro => $val_pro){
                if($res_check_pro['JADWAL_PROJECT'] == $val_pro){
                    $col_name = $key_pro;
                }
            }

            $data['ACTIVITY']       = "UPDATE";
            $data['OLD_VALUE']      = $res_check_pro['JADWAL_PROJECT'];
            $data['NEW_VALUE']      = $na_pro;
            $data['COL_AFFECTED']   = $col_name;
            $data['TABLE_AFFECTED'] = "PM_REQUIREMENT_PROJECT"; //How to get table name automatically??
            $data['ANNOTATION']     = NULL;
            $data['EXECUTOR']       = $this->session->userdata('nip');
            $data['CHANGED_ON']     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data['CHANGED_BY']     = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $data['STATUS']         = 1;

            $this->MProject->ins_system_log($data);             
        }


    }


}
```

This is used for saving a log file for update. So, if a data is updated then it store a log in a table.

Comment: it is about codereview and should be ask at [codereview.SE]

Comment: Please give some more details.But as of my current understanding the work you cant to do can do by database itself in the better way. please share if which db you are using. read triggers concept which can be fire on table updation and do the relevent operation.

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal I use mySQL. I just want to simplify the foreach loop if possible. The script working fine. But, kinda takes a lot of space/line

Comment: @Shota But why don't you use db functionality if they are providing and again  please share the complete use case which example then only we can help you.

Comment: what else should I post?